# Best practice to edit make changes to old commits with git

Tags: git

I'm not very experienced with using git in large project settings, but I just went through this [stunning visual tutorial](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/). One thing that I don't understand is that in one exercise, it tasks you with making a small change to code from a previous commit (changing the dimensions of an image). To do so, it has you reorder the commits so that the commit that added the code with the old dimensions is on top, amend that commit, and then reorder everything back to the way it was.

The result is that you don't have an extra little commit that fixes the dimensions of an image, but instead you have a bunch of junk artifacts of all the rebasing or cherry-picking.

What is the advantage of the technique presented in the tutorial over simply adding a new commit? Or maybe if in this specific case it's overkill but in some other context there's a good reason, then what is an example and why is it not overkill in its context? As I see it, it's just dogma, but since I'm so inexperienced, I'm sure I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A rule of thumb :** If the commit we would like to change was previously pushed on a shared repository, don't amend / rebase / rewrite history. Just do another commit on top of the branch, then push it.

---

So let's say the commit (`C1`) you have to change is only on a local branch. `C1` adds a picture and some changes linked to the picture.

If you make another commit `C2` on top (which only change the picture), if you later want to cherry pick the content of the feature brought by `C1`, you have to cherry-pick both `C1` (initial picture and other changes) and `C2` (updated image).

Still, in most daily cases, you would simply do another commit. Such "feature branch crafting" can be usefull before making a pull request for open source project, as it makes your commits clean and atomic, and as such, easier to review.

Comment: It is worth explaining *why it is so bad to change commits already pushed in repo* -- if you have your own [feature] branch and no one else is sharing it with you I doubt there will be any problems.

Comment: Nice answer! Like [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) in time rather than space (unfortunately, *temporal cohesion* is already taken).

Answer (score 2):

One reason is to make the commit history easier to understand.

It's similar to considering a program to be written not for the computer, but for another human (there's arguments for more comments, less comments or even no comments - but everyone agrees clarity is good).
It's like the difference between a paper draft of an essay with red pen corrections all over it, and a fresh draft, rewritten without all the distracting false starts and mistakes.

In your scenario of committing a new feature, committing several other features, then committing a small change to that previous feature (bugfix/typo/etc), keeping the history the way it actually happened might be easier for you to understand, because you remember doing that fix (or possibly forms a narrative, where the change makes much more sense if you first see the initial version; it depends on if it's clearer) - but it's usually unnecessarily complicated to someone else seeing it fresh. For them, it would be simpler for it to appear as if the feature was done right in the first place.

Finally, their specific approach of reordering, amending then reordering again seems unnecessarily complex to me. I would just rebase interactively (`git rebase -i parent_of_commit_to_be_changed`), mark that commit for amending (by changing "pick" to "edit" or "e"), edit the file, and so on following the instructions git gives you.

(**NB**: this is only for preparing your own private repository *before pushing* - as @GuillaumeDarmont said, modifying history *after pushing* makes trouble for anyone who's already fetched/pulled it.)